# How can I get the output of a command into a bash variable?

Tags: bash

I can't remember how to capture the result of an execution into a variable in a bash script.

Basically I have a folder full of backup files of the following format:
`backup--my.hostname.com--1309565.tar.gz`

I want to loop over a list of all files and pull the numeric part out of the filename and do something with it, so I'm doing this so far:

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
DIR="/backups/"
SUFFIX=".tar.gz"
PREFIX="backup--$HOSTNAME--"
TESTNUMBER=9999999999


#move into the backup dir
cd $DIR

#get a list of all backup files in there
FILES=$PREFIX*$SUFFIX

#Loop over the list
for F in $FILES
do
    #rip the number from the filename
    NUMBER=$F | sed s/$PREFIX//g | sed s/$SUFFIX//g

   #compare the number with another number

   if [ $NUMBER -lg $TESTNUMBER ]
      #do something

   fi

done
```

I know the `"$F | sed s/$PREFIX//g | sed s/$SUFFIX//g"` part rips the number correctly (though I appreciate there might be a better way of doing this), but I just can't remember how to get that result into NUMBER so I can reuse it in the if statement below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$(...)` syntax (or ``).

```
NUMBER=$( echo $F | sed s/$PREFIX//g | sed s/$SUFFIX//g )
```

or

```
NUMBER=` echo $F | sed s/$PREFIX//g | sed s/$SUFFIX//g `
```

(I prefer the first one, since it is easier to see when multiple ones nest.)

Comment: The only problem I ever have with the `$(...)` style, is that these days, I think I'm looking at jQuery. ;-)

Comment: That's what I tried initially (without the cat) but this doesn't seem to do the job. Rather than capturing the number i.e. the result of the filename passed through sed a couple of times) it seems to return the whole filename...

Comment: About `cat`, this should of course be `echo`. I did not fully read the question ...

Comment: @Orbling: The problem with the `` style is that it conflicts with the inline highlighting on Stack Overflow :-p

Comment: Nice one Paŭlo thanks! Any other day of the week and I'd have realised that's what I was missing too :)

Answer (score 0):

Backticks if you want to be portable to older shells (sh):

```
NUMBER=`$F | sed s/$PREFIX//g | sed s/$SUFFIX//g`.
```

Otherwise, use `NUMBER=$($F | sed s/$PREFIX//g | sed s/$SUFFIX//g)`. It's better and supports nesting more readily.